# My MPPT controller has same voltage in solar input and battery output

Tags: solar-charge-controller

When I measure voltage in the solar input of my MPPT controller, it shows about the same voltage as the voltage of the battery output (about 12.3 V).

Is this normal?

The solar panels if not connected delivers about 20 V.

My understanding is that solar input and battery output are on two different circuits. The solar circuit is supposed to optimize the power by converting voltage surplus into current, as opposed to a PWM controller that limits the solar voltage to the battery voltage.

Am I missing something or is my MPPT controller actually a PWM controller in disguise?

Comment: I would also suspect PWM controller, but your solar panel’s IV-curve, irradiation and power drawn from the battery charging _may_ happen to put it at equal voltage to your battery voltage. Break it open and post photos!

Answer (score 1):

A MPPT charger's output is determined by the battery voltage, and charging current is maximised by making the solar panel sit at its MPP.

The MPP's voltage is not equal to the solar panel's open-circuit voltage, but equal to the voltage where P=V·I is maximal on the solar panel's IV curve.

MPPT chargers find this MPP by maximising output charging current by varying the input impedance of a buck converter. The output of the buck converter behaves much like a current source, so the battery sets the voltage.

The buck converter converts V<sub>in</sub>·I<sub>in</sub> to V<sub>out</sub>·I<sub>out</sub> with high efficiency; it does not simply "limit the voltage".

The MPP voltage of the solar panel can be about equal to the battery voltage depending on the type of solar panel, illumination, and the state of charge of the battery, but shouldn't always be. You could look up (or measure) the MPP voltage of your solar panel under full sun and see if this is the voltage your MPPT charger sets when charging. If it does not, something is wrong.

Seeing the same input voltage and output voltage under all circumstances is the behaviour of a solar panel connected to a buck converter (or something else) that tries to regulate its output voltage instead of trying to vary its input impedance to find the solar panel's MPP. If that is what you see, it is not a MPPT charger.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tested this morning with low sun, and now is quite sunny, and the voltage from the solar input (12.8v) is about the same as the output for battery (12.7v). I have 4 solar panels in parallel, they are not the same but the maximum power voltage of the lowest unit is 18V and maximum current at 5.5A. Since it's quite sunny I would assume the input voltage to be closer to 18v isn't it?